# Changes to a suggested edit between approvals/rejections should reset any votes on it

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, suggested-edits

On smaller sites it is possible for suggested edits to sit in the review queues for very long, so there is scope for manipulating the suggested edits after only one review has come in but before it gets approved/rejected. For instance, suggested edits on Music Fans SE take [48 hours on average](https://data.stackexchange.com/musicfans/query/350400/maxium-minutes-of-suggested-edit-before-final) to be fully reviewed. This is enough time for changes to be made to a suggested edit between approvals/rejections.

I have actually done this when I noticed that my suggested edit could do with some minor improvements. For example, consider [this suggested edit](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/74) of mine to a tag wiki on Music Fans Meta. I didn't notice that it contained a broken link when I submitted the edit. After it received one approval, I changed the broken link and noted the change in the edit summary — but, the first approval still remains. Now, the approver has no way to know that a change was made and that they approved a different version of the suggested edit. (I don't know whether the original version of the suggested edit is even saved anywhere for comparison.)

This is far from ideal. If a change is made to a suggested edit after it has received a vote, then that vote is meaningless: it is for a different suggested edit compared to the final version that is approved/rejected.

**Feature request:** Any updates to a suggested edit (by the user who suggested it) should reset any votes on the edit.

Comment: This idea has merit, but do note that on sites like Music Fans it may take even longer for an edit to be reviewed. Also, will the reviewer be able to review the edit again (I assume so - that would still be confusing to them.)

Comment: @Glorfindel I think it's not a problem if it takes longer - it's more important that an edit is reviewed for what it is, rather than what it was. Regarding the potential confusion for a reviewer who had reviewed it earlier, I'm not sure what a good solution would be.

Comment: It would seem that [if a subsequent reviewer makes a change (improve or R&E)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/282094) that prior votes are reset; it's a lot fuzzy if the FAQ says that the OP's re-edits have the same effect, but it seems that the FAQ implies that (even if it's not true). Either action should be consistent, but it's odd that trusted edits reset and untrusted ones do not.

Comment: @JamesA For the case I mentioned, I just navigate to the [tag info page](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-ads/info) for the relevant tag, and click on "Edit tag info". This loads my previously suggested edit, and I can now make changes to it.

Comment: @Rob If a subsequent reviewer chooses to either "Improve Edit" or "Reject & Edit", then their edit becomes binding, but the prior votes are not reset, they are still logged in the review info.